# Can I get a one-to-many(many-to-many) transaction method?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, wallets

As we know, geth send eth by `sendTransaction`, it has `from` `to` and `amount`, it is an one-to-one transaction.
Can I get a way of one-to-many(many-to-many) transaction like `sendmany` in bitcoin-core? As bitcoin-core can draw bitcoin form all address in the local wallet automatically, it is actually a many-to-many transaction.
Just for saving miner-fee when I have huge transactions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is not native method in Ethereum that can do that but you can write a smart contract that is able to do it.

For example this one
https://github.com/cleanunicorn/smart-split

Has users defined as partners

```
// partnerAdd adds a new partner to the list
// It saves the partner address and the weight of the partner
function partnerAdd(address partner, uint256 weight) public onlyOwnerOrPartner  {
    require(partnerExists(partner) == false);

    partners.push(partner);
    partnersWeight.push(weight);
}
```

And in the function that receives ETH can split the funds based on your logic

```
function () public payable {
    uint256 sum;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < partners.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + partnersWeight[i];
    }
    Sum(sum);

    for (i = 0; i < partners.length; i++) {
        address dst = partners[i];
        uint256 value = msg.value * partnersWeight[i] / sum;
        dst.transfer(value);

        SplitValue(dst, partnersWeight[i], value);
    }
}
```